# What are the security risks of allowing users to add iframes?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, iframe

In my web app I'm using a good [sanitizer](https://github.com/emil2k/bluemonday) which let's me to whitelist some specific html tags.
I'd like to allow `<iframe>` so that users can insert youtube videos and so on.
However I'm worried about vulnerabilities that this approach would introduce.
So not sure this is a safe idea.
Appreciate your hints about this.

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/197068

Answer (score 1):

"As soon as you're displaying content from another domain, you're basically trusting that domain not to serve-up malware.
There's nothing wrong with iframes per se. If you control the content of the iframe, they're perfectly safe." - Shamelessly stolen from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289139/why-are-iframes-considered-dangerous-and-a-security-risk).

However your web app could be vulnerable if there is XSS vulnerability inside the iframe content. You can mitigating this by setting the `sandbox` attribute.